# Get directions between two geopoints

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have seen numerous answers on this subject but none of them have given me a correct solution. I must make it clear that I don't want a polyline drew between the two geopoints. I want the directions to appear in a textview e.g:

1: In 100 yards turn right

below shows the code that I currently have but it takes me online and gives me directions but I want the directions to appear in a textview. How can the code be manipulated to achieve this?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=55.006108,-7.322766&destination=55.013534,-7.318560&sensor=false"));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the google maps API, rather than trying to parse a HTML page. Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

You can call it like this: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=20.344,34.34&destination=20.5666,45.345&sensor=false`

FYI, those co-ordinates aren't valid for directions because they aren't on roads, so you will get back an error code when pasing them into the API.

Comment: the coordinates where only being used as an example to make it clearer what was going on but I will have a look at that API

Comment: I have looked at this documentation and I don't really understand how to implement it!

Comment: change your code to parse a JSON object (returned by `URI.parse`), then look at the JSON structure in a browser, and determine what info you want to display in the text view.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, is there a tutorial you know of that could help or even better if you could give me a hand with it!

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=google+json+java+example&oq=google+java+json+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l3j69i64.6316j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8